# Reverse a substring from a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, complexity-theory

I am looking for better algorithm to solve a problem.

**Problem: Check a given string if given substring is present and reverse all the substrings in the given string.**

Example: String:

> Can you can a can as a canner can can a can

Substring:

> can

Output:

> nac you nac a nac as a nacner nac nac a nac

What would be a better algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your current algorithm if you are looking for a better one?

Comment: I am just thinking of brute force method comparing substring at each character of the string.

Comment: Once you have an algorithm and aren't just thinking about one, perhaps ask a question with a specific problem you have with it. "Better" can mean lots of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first search for those substrings using [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and then you can simply replace them with the reverse order.

As I've passed my Data Structure course in university, this algorithm has a very good performance, in [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Efficiency_of_the_search_algorithm) point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In Java,
You can use a HashMap to store the key as the word and the value as the reversed word.

For every word, check if it exists in the hashmap, if yes, then fetch the value.
If it does not, reverse the word and add it to the hashmap.

You can use the reverse method of the StringBuilder Class to reverse a word in place.